# AWS APIGateway & Lambda - How to call function right before iOS App terminates?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have been working with AWS for a little while now and I am starting to get the hang of APIGateway and Lambda. I have just made a Lambda function that receives the username entered by a user and then uses the AdminDeleteUser function to delete that user from the user pool, and it works fine. I even have it set up with APIGateway to be used in XCode and it works fine with that as well.

**Problem**
My problem is, is that I am trying to have the Lambda function run right as the user terminates the iOS app. I am using a NotificationCenter observer to watch when the App terminates, that all works well except the fact that I believe the Lambda function's call is cancelled once the app fully terminates, meaning it can't complete the full request. My lambda function essentially checks if the username that is being received is a user who is unconfirmed, and if they are unconfirmed then they are deleted from the user pool. I am doing this on the screen where the user has to confirm a confirmation code that was sent via SMS

**Question**
So I  guess the questions I have are,

1. Is it possible to call a Lambda function while the App is terminating?
2. If not, is it possible to delete the current user from the user pool if they are not confirmed, before the App exits?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what is happening is exactly what you have described above. The app is exiting before the connection can be made to the service.

A better design might be to have a process run at X interval ([using a Lambda scheduled event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)) to automatically remove any unconfirmed users from your data store.

**Edit:**

When searching for unconfirmed users, you should be able to use the `UserCreateDate` field to check if the user has registered within your specified amount of time. If 'createDate' falls within that time, ignore that user.

[ListUsers API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you suggesting that I have a Lambda function run, lets say every 24 hours which loops through my list of users, deleting all unconfirmed ones?

Comment: Yes, or even more frequently say 1 to 2 hours (depending on your user base) That way you don't have to worry about timing or race conditions when dealing with application exit. Also, I don't know if I would loop as they are expensive operations. If setup appropriately, you could just runa simple query: (psudeo) delete * where unconfirmed = 1

Comment: Upon doing some testing with this, this solution can be problematic because during the Sign Up process, the user creating the account is set to unconfirmed. Meaning if the lambda function happens to run while a user is signing up, it will delete that user and return an error when the user attempts to finish. None the less, thank you for your input.

Comment: In that case, you could just add another column that would specify that the user has registered (unconfirmed) but is new (less than a certain number of hours/days old) to prevent that sort of thing

Comment: You can do that with AWS Cognito User Pools? If you have the time, could you possibly link me to the documentation for that?

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't see the Cognito tag on your original question. In that case, you should be able to use the UserCreateDate to ignore users that are within a few hours of signing up so they do not get removed. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ehh thank you very much, really appreciate it man . I'm assuming you were talking about DynamoDB when you mentioned the columns thing.